# Coming "down" or "up" (traveling from one place to another)

Tags: traducción

In English (at least US English), it is common to use "up" and "down" when giving directions. For example:

- When are you coming down to visit us?
- I went up to see him for the weekend.

The "up" and "down" can refer to either north/south or higher/lower elevation. Are there equivalent terms in Spanish? What would be the most natural translation of sentences like these?

Comment: Not only you can use _subir_ and _bajar_ in the same situations, but you can say _Subir [bajar] por la calle Velázquez_ to mean you walked it in ascending [descending] house number order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si alguien vive en la montaña y va hacia un valle, es común (coloquialmente) decir:

> "¿Cuándo vas a bajar a visitarnos?"

exactamente lo mismo vale para "subir"

WRT the Notrth-South orientation, depends on the region, but yes, I've heard it many times (but more colloquial yet than the previous usage)

**Edit**

However, the common use to add "up" or "down" to round up the sound of some verbs in English hasn't  a correlation in Spanish.